# Makefile pattern rules differences

Tags: c++, c, makefile

What is the difference between `.cpp.o:`, `.o:` and `%.o: %.c`?
Here's a simple Makefile example:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
SOURCES=file1.cpp file2.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=program

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

#.o:
#.cpp.o:
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

I have noticed that the output is same, but I guess they are interpreted on a different way internally. 
Is there a preferred way of doing this?

Comment: My preferred way is *not having* any joker rule. I use one rule per source file, in order to manage dependencies on `.h` files as well a some other things.

Comment: I agree that rules per file are nice, especially for small projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.cpp.o:    # build *.o from *.cpp (old style notation)

%.o: %.c   # build *.o from *.c (new style notation)
```

Both work but the new style is more powerful because it allows you to write more complicated constructions thanks to pattern matching:

```
%.uuu: %.vvv %.www
```

Comment: I have noticed that makefile from my example will not take into account -g option if I use %.o: %.c rule

Comment: @kometonja [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) doesn't seem to support the `-g` option.